# ¿Se cierra la activity al apretar un botón, alguien sabe el motivo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Estoy tratando de programar el juego de Simon, que consiste en que se genere una secuencia de colores y luego vayas replicando dicha secuencia, a medida que vayas acertando la longitud de la cadena irá aumentando.

Soy nuevo en esto de Android Studio y no puedo encontrar el error, cuestión que luego de que se muestre la secuencia, cuando toca que uno la replique, la activity se cierra al apretar el botón acertado. Si se oprime el incorrecto no pasa nada, salta a la activity del final. Me gustaría saber si alguien tiene idea por qué se da el error.

Código:

```
public class SimonGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] arrayColores = {"verde", "rojo", "amarillo","azul"};
    List<String> listRondas= new ArrayList<>();
    private Button btnGreen;
    private Button btnRed;
    private Button btnYellow;
    private Button btnBlue;
    private TextView pntj;
    private int punt;
    private int rondaAct;
    private boolean apagado;
    private String dificultad;
    private int delay;
    private String colorRandom;
    private String colorActual;
    private int iRondas;
    private int rondasTotal;
    private int maxFacil;
    private int maxMedio;
    private int maxDificil;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simon_game);

        //recibo la dificultad y la declaro
        Bundle dato = getIntent().getExtras();
        delay = dato.getInt("dificult");
        switch (delay){
            case 1000 : dificultad = "facil";
                break;
            case 700 : dificultad = "medio";
                break;
            case 900 : dificultad = "dificil";
                break;
        }

        //obtengo las id
        btnGreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bgreen);
        btnRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bred);
        btnYellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Byellow);
        btnBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bblue);
        pntj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.puntaje);

        //obtengo los preferences
        preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        maxFacil = preferences.getInt("mFacil",0);
        maxMedio= preferences.getInt("mMedio",0);
        maxDificil = preferences.getInt("mDificl",0);

        punt = 0;
        rondaAct = 0;
        apagado = true;
        iRondas = 0;
        rondasTotal = 0;
        //seteo a cada boton el OnClickListener
        btnGreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //efecto de encendido y apagado con sonido
                encender(1);
                //sonar(1);
                apagar();
                //pregunto si es correcto que aprete este boton
                colorActual="verde";
                if (colorActual.equals(listRondas.get(iRondas).toString())) {
                    iRondas++;
                    //pregunto si es el final de la secuencia
                    if (iRondas==rondasTotal) {
                        rondasTotal++;
                        pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
                        recorrerSecuencia();
                    }

                } else {
                    finJuego();
                }
            }
        });
        btnRed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                encender(2);
                //sonar(2);
                apagar();
                colorActual="rojo";
                if (colorActual.equals(listRondas.get(iRondas))) {
                    iRondas++;
                    if (iRondas==rondasTotal) {
                        rondasTotal++;
                        pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
                        recorrerSecuencia();
                    }

                } else {
                    finJuego();
                }
            }
        });
        btnYellow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                encender(3);
                //sonar(3);
                apagar();
                colorActual="amarillo";
                if (colorActual.equals(listRondas.get(iRondas))) {
                    iRondas++;
                    if (iRondas==rondasTotal) {
                        rondasTotal++;
                        pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
                        recorrerSecuencia();
                    }

                } else {
                    finJuego();
                }
            }
        });
        btnBlue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                encender(4);
                //sonarRojo(4);
                apagar();
                colorActual="azul";
                if (colorActual.equals(listRondas.get(iRondas))) {
                    iRondas++;
                    if (iRondas==rondasTotal) {
                        rondasTotal++;
                        pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
                        recorrerSecuencia();
                    }

                } else {
                    finJuego();
                }
            }
        });

        //llamo a recorrerSecuencia() para iniciar el juego
        recorrerSecuencia();
    }

    //declaracion del menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.menuppal,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i;
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menuFacil : i = new Intent(this,SimonGame.class);
                i.putExtra("dificult",1000);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.menuMedio : i = new Intent(this,SimonGame.class);
                i.putExtra("dificult",700);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.menuDificil : i = new Intent(this,SimonGame.class);
                i.putExtra("dificult",900);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.menuPuntajes : i = new Intent(this,SimonPoint.class);
                i.putExtra("mFacil",maxFacil);
                i.putExtra("mMedio",maxMedio);
                i.putExtra("mDificil",maxDificil);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.menuEnd : finish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    //enciende el boton dependiendo del parametro de entrada
    protected void encender (int aux){
        if (aux == 1){
            btnGreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bgreen);
            btnGreen.setBackgroundResource(R.color.greenOn);
        }else if (aux ==  2) {
            btnRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bred);
            btnRed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redOn);
        }else if (aux == 3){
            btnYellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Byellow);
            btnYellow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellowOn);
        }else if (aux == 4) {
            btnBlue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bblue);
            btnBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blueOn);
        }
    }

    //apaga todos los botones
    protected void apagar (){
        btnGreen.setBackgroundResource(R.color.greenOff);
        btnRed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.redOff);
        btnYellow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellowOff);
        btnBlue.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blueOff);
    }

    //genera un nodo mas y recorre toda la secuencia
    protected void recorrerSecuencia (){
        colorRandom = generarRandom();
        listRondas.add(rondasTotal,colorRandom);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (apagado){
                    apagado = false;
                    colorActual =listRondas.get(rondaAct);
                    switch (colorActual){
                        case "verde" : encender(1);
                            break;
                        case "rojo" : encender(2);
                            break;
                        case "amarillo" : encender(3);
                            break;
                        case "azul" : encender(4);
                            break;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                } else {
                    apagado = true;
                    apagar();
                    rondaAct++;
                    if (rondaAct<listRondas.size()){
                        handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                    }
                }
            }
        },delay);

        if (rondasTotal==4 && dificultad.equals("dificil")){
            delay = delay - 150;
        }
        if (rondasTotal==8 && dificultad.equals("dificil")){
            delay = delay - 150;
        }
        if (rondasTotal==12 && dificultad.equals("dificil")) {
            delay = delay - 150;
        }
        rondaAct = 0;
        rondasTotal++;
        iRondas = 0;
    }

    //genera un nodo random
    public String  generarRandom(){
        Random random = new Random();
        return arrayColores[random.nextInt(arrayColores.length)];
    }

    //guarda en preferences el puntaje maximo
    private void guardarPreferencia(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        switch (dificultad){
            case "facil" : editor.putInt("mFacil",punt);
                break;
            case "medio" : editor.putInt("mMedio",punt);
                break;
            case "dificil" : editor.putInt("mDificil",punt);
                break;
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    //fin de juego
    protected void finJuego(){
        punt = Integer.parseInt(pntj.getText().toString());
        Intent iFin = new Intent(this,simon_end.class);
        iFin.putExtra("puntaje",punt);
        if (punt > maxFacil && dificultad.equals("facil")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Nuevo puntaje maximo en el modo facil",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            guardarPreferencia();
        }else if (punt > maxMedio && dificultad.equals("medio")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Nuevo puntaje maximo en el modo medio",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            guardarPreferencia();
        }else if (punt > maxDificil && dificultad.equals("dificil")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Nuevo puntaje maximo en el modo dificil",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            guardarPreferencia();
        }
        startActivity(iFin);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te aparece en el log cuando se cierra el activity?

Comment: lo unico que me aparece es esto "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]", nada mas

Comment: Te sugiero aprendas a usar el LogCat y filtrar los mensajes por aplicación, determinar cual es el problema en este caso es dificil, lo cual pudiera ser demasiado sencillo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el XML del layout de la actividad?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no veo mal, al poner:

```
listRondas.add(rondasTotal,colorRandom);
```

estarías saliendo del indice, ademas de ser redundante ya que `rondasTotal` siempre incrementa en 1. Prueba a colocar:

```
listRondas.add(colorRandom);
```

No obstante, veo algun problema que podrias tener, por ejemplo en cada click para ver el final de ronda, comparas el valor de `iRondas` y `rondasTotal`, en tu primera ejecucion deberia funcionar correctamente, ya que ambas variables tienen el mismo valor, pero cuando pasas a la segunda ronda, iRondas valdra 1 y rondasTotal tambien vale 1, pero al hacer un click en un boton, iRondas valdra 2, por lo que nunca entrara en la condicion, me refiero exactamente a esto:

```
if (iRondas==rondasTotal) {
    rondasTotal++;
    pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
    recorrerSecuencia();
}
```

Para solventar eso te dejo un ejemplo siguiendo el esquema de tu codigo, crea una variable de clase

```
private int cantidad;
```

en tu metodo onCreate, iniciala:

```
cantidad = 0;
```

en tu metodo recorrerSecuencia, suma 1 al valor de cantidad:

```
cantidad = cantidad + 1;
```

Por ultimo, usala en el if dentro de los 4 botones quedando de esta manera:

```
if (iRondas==contador) {
    rondasTotal++;
    pntj.setText(Integer.toString(rondasTotal));
    recorrerSecuencia();
}
```

Aun habiendote dicho todo esto, estaria bien que probaras unicamente la solucion que propuse a tu pregunta, y veas si tienes el error que creo se te podria presentar, y en caso de tenerlo, apliques la respuesta adicional que he propuesto.

Comment: muchas gracias, era ese el error que tenia!