# Pregunta Android OnClick

Tags: android, android-studio, botón, onclick

hola una consulta el tema es asi tengo un onclick que genera un numero dependiendo el boton que presiones (de 1 a 4) y tengo un handler que en determinado momento tiene que pausarse y esperar a que se presionen dichos botones y compararlo con un array list que tengo. no se como hacer para llamar al onclick y que el programa espere la respuesta de los botones para continuar 
yo use boton1.callOnClick(); pero ahi uso uno solo de los botones y ademas no me pide apretar el boton para continuar

este es el handler

```
   public void iniciarTimer() {
    c=0;
    encender=true;
    n = 0;
    generar();
    final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    numero = list.get(n);
                    if (encender == true) {
                        if (finalizar == false) {
                            switch (numero) {
                                case 1:

                                    boton1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                    boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                    boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    boton2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                                    boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                    boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                    boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    boton3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                    boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                    boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                    boton4.setBackgroundResource(R.color.amarillo);
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    boton4.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                    boton3.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                                    boton2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.verde);
                                    boton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
                                    break;
                            }
//condicion para que aumente n +1 despues de la primer pasada del handler, 
ya que el primer color lo prende en la segunda pasada
                            if (c != 0) {
                                n++;
                            }
                            c++;
//limite de puntos en el juego
                            if (n > 10) {
                                finalizar = true;
                                encender = false;
                                fin();
                            }
//en nivel dificil que valla aumentando la velocidad
                            dificil = nivel;
                            if (dificil == 750) {
                                nivel = (nivel - 10);
                            }
// una vez que se recorre la lista que entre en el if para comparar
                            if (n == list.size()) {
// recorrer la lista
                                for (a = (0); a < (list.size()); a++) {
// esperar un valor de p al presionar un boton.
                                    p = 0;
                                    if (p == 0) {
                                        a--;
                                    }
// comparar si el boton presionado coincide con el de la lista de no ser asi 
que finalize la activity
                                    if (p != 0) {
                                        if (list.get(a) != p) {
                                            encender = false;
                                            finalizar = true;
                                            fin();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
// si todos los botones coiniciden inicia el timer de vuelta para generar 
otro numero y arrancar a recorrer de 0
                                encender = false;

                            }
                            if (encender == true) {
                                if (finalizar == false) {
                                    handler.postDelayed(this, nivel);
                                }
                            } else {
//suma el punto si todos los botones coinciden y reinicia el timer para 
generar otro numero y arrancar a recorrer de 0
                                sumar();
                                apagar();
                                iniciarTimer();
                            }
                        } else {
                            apagar();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    }).start();
}
```

este es el Onclick (use onClickListener)

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
            p = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.b2:
            p = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.b3:
            p = 3;
            break;
        case R.id.b4:
            p = 4;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez podrias orientarlo de una manera menos rebuscada. Tras generar la secuencia de colores has de pulsar los botones, podrias ademas de asignar el numero como haces, llamar al handler, y no hacer que este se repita cada segundo como estas haciendo en tu codigo. Disculpa si me pueda equivocar ya que no se si es lo que buscas, pero si lo he entendido bien creo que podria solventarte tu problema ademas de ahorrar el ejecutar un codigo constantemente.

Comment: el tema es este, es el juego de mesa simon, que se prende un boton, luego vos presionas ese boton si es correcto se prende el boton anterior y uno nuevo, y tenes que presionar el viejo y el nuevo boton y asi susecivamente hasta llegar a 50 que fue el limite que le puse yo, cada boton que se genera aleatoriamente entre 1 y 4 lo voy guardando en la lista, lo que yo necesito es que  en el if (n==list.size) pida seleccionar uno de los 4 botones y el resultado del onclick (p) se compare en el siguiente if si es correcto que siga con el proximo boton (para eso es el for)

Comment: El handler, se encarga de encender el boton pulsado por la persona y comprobarlo en la lista cierto ? para saber si finalizar el juego por error, o continuar en caso de acierto

Comment: no el if n==list.size es el que se encarga de eso, el handler va prendiendo los botones que estan en la lista, no los que selecciona, se genera un boton list.size pasa a ser 1, se prende el boton, y n+1, si n = list.size que pidra presionar el boton para ver si es correcto o no) si es correcto inicia el timer de vuelta si no es correcto finaliza, si inicia timer de vuelta n=0 genera otro numero list size es 2, ahora n distinto list.size, entonces enceder sigue siendo true y se prende otro boton, n=2 asique tiene que comparar los 2 botones (por eso el for dentro de n==list.size)

Comment: yo lo que necesito es que el programa PIDA/ESPERE una respuesta del onclick(para que me de p y pueda comparar), no se que comando utilizar,acordarse que el onclick es de 4 botones

Comment: Ayer respondi una pregunta sobre el mismo juego, podrias echarle un vistazo a su estructura: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83115/se-cierra-la-activity-al-apretar-un-bot%C3%B3n-alguien-sabe-el-motivo/83151#83151
No obstante, desconozco si hay una funcion especifica para esperar un click, pero dado que tu ciclo se repite, puedes "reiniciar" el valor de p a 0 al terminar el handler, en el for, comprobar si es 0, en caso de serlo, resta 1 a la variable a (a--), para que se mantenga constantemente en el bucle hasta que p tenga un valor superior a 0

Comment: debe ser alguno de mi clase tambien que esta con lo mismo aun que el lo hizo muy distinto a lo que hice yo, y como llamo al onclick? por que me tira un error de View que no se que es, y si lo llamo con boton1.callonclick siempre p es 1

Comment: sisis pero yo tengo que llamar a OnClick(); y no me lo permite me sale
`Error:(167, 28) error: method onClick in class MainActivity2 cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length`
el listener lo tengo aplicado en la clase

Comment: buena idea esa pero ahora no me prende ni los botones voy a ver que anda pasando gracias por la ayuda! :)

Comment: logre hacer que prenda y espere pero no me toma onclick, y en otros momentos durante la prueba si me lo tomaba

Comment: puede ser que por que quede en un bucle infinito no me deje usar el onclick?

Comment: un bucle infinito si congelaria la inerfaz, para solventar eso unicamente necesitas ejecutarlo en un nuevo Thread o Runnable y tendrias aislado el proceso de tu handler y la interfaz, Es decir, cuando inicias el handler, hazlo dentro de un nuevo thread: `new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //aqui inicias el handler
        }
    }).start();`

Comment: ahi me diste con un caño, igual justo cerre todo mañana lo pruebo y te digo que tal me sale, si eso funciona mi programa estaria terminado

Comment: probe lo que me dijiste, del new thread pero me sigue sin tomar la interfaz, edito el post para mostrarte como esta el codigo ahora

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?